# Prove that if $x$ is odd then $x^2 + (x + 2)^2$ is divisible by $2$ but not for $4$

Tags: divisibility

This is what I tried:

$$x^2 + x^2 + 4x + 4=2x^2 + 4(x + 1),$$

so it's divisible by $2$, since this expression is a sum of a multiple of $2$ and a multiple of $4$.
Therefore, for the expression not to be a multiple of $4$, $2x^2$ can't be multiple of $4$, that's what I can't prove.
Brazilian student, sorry for my English.

Comment: It's the sum of an *odd* multiple of $2$ and a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Yep, now I noticed. x^2 should be divisible by 2, so that, when multiplied by 2, would be a multiple of 4. Thanks bro! That's what I didn't think

Comment: Please edit the title of your post.

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Sorry? Edit how?

Comment: if $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ is odd.  Alternatively, replace $x$ with $2n+1$

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the easiest way is to put $x=2k-1$, $k$ an integer, since $x$ is odd. Then
$$ x^2+(x+2)^2 = (2k-1)^2+(2k+1)^2 = 8k^2+2, $$
which is clearly $2$ more than a multiple of $4$, and hence not a multiple of $4$ (but is $2(4k^2+1)$, so obviously a multiple of $2$).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$x^2+(x+2)^2=\{(x+2)-x\}^2+2x(x+2)$$

As $x$ is odd $\iff x+2$ is odd, so will be $x(x+2)$